# Trouble installing nopcommerce with webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, nopcommerce

I am trying to install nopCommerce using webmatrix on my localhost and everything goes just fine until I go to visit the site and complete the installation. I get to the second page and I use integrated windows administration. After clicking next I get this error....

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have that issue every time I go to install NopCommerce. Your host needs to be /SQLEXPRESS I believe and if I remember correctly you need to go into your database via SQL Server Management and add your windows user to the database with all the privileges on the Database.

Comment: I do not have sql server management. All I have is the config manager.

Comment: I believe that you may have the connection info incorrect more than the permissions.

Comment: how do you manage sql server express witout sql server management?

Comment: You could use sql server express as well. You can install via Webmatrix